# How to open a web page inside a xpage

Tags: xpages

I'm slowly transitioning to xpages.  It's going to take quite a while since we have quite a few apps to migrate.

As a start, I'm migrating a frameset page.  The links in the navigation frame open Notes dbs as well as pages dynamically generated by the execution of agents.  With (much appreciated) help from a couple guys here, I got the Application Layout control figured out which will replace the frameset.  What I'm having a bit of trouble with is figuring out how to embed some of these Notes apps into an xPage so I can open them in the center facet of the Layout Control.  I played around with a computed field and even tried an Include Page control but I've not had success.  I'm sure the solution is simple and have been searching but have not come up with anything.  Thoughts?

Thanks!
clem

Comment: So .. just to clarify: is it that effectively you're wanting to include the results of xyz.nsf?OpenDatabase into a facet in a Custom control ?

Comment: That's right.. as well as other Notes urls like xyz.nsf/List?open&v6 which returns a bunch of Print statements from the agent.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try an iframe? Just put the source code into the source tab of the XPage.

Comment: I would agree with this.  You're just containing a non XPage so an iFrame should work well I'd think.

Comment: Make sure to test the iframe solution with multiple browsers. IE has some weird security settings if source and destination are not both http/https

Comment: Ok, I added a computed field in the center facet of the Layout Control, entered a iframe tags pointing to a web form from one of the apps and that worked.  I'm having some trouble with the hieght of the iframe which I'm working on.

Comment: I ended up having to specify the height in px's.  Looks like there's issues with iframe sizing.  This isn't the best solution but it works for now.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IFrame is the general approach. You can have 3 variations:

- directly use an IFrame as suggested in the other answer
- use the dojo panel control from the Extlib. It allows to compute the URL easily

  - go "hardcore" and load the HTML serverside using Java code. I don't think that this is needed for your scenario

My bet would be on the dojo panel

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get really fancy you could add this plugin or some similar plugin to your site.

It might get you some better control over the sizing and some eye candy to go with it.

http://www.artviper.net/website-tools/bumpbox-lightbox.php
http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the iFrame approach (there are reasons not to- eg you have to define the size of an iframe and handle 'what if the loaded page is larger' etc, plus the page delivered needs its own styling), you could get the 'sub-page' results through an Ajax call, strip a bit of the HTML out with javascript (eg the  etc) and and plug them into the relevant page on the screen.

I guess you could do that with partial refresh on a panel (I  think? not sure if the controls will let you do that) or straightforward Javascript / dojo /c jquery.